# Video as voxels in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, framebuffer

Any good references on displaying sequence of images from a video as voxel data in OpenGL? I want to display all these images at once as a cuboid with 50% alpha and navigate using keyboard or mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial](http://gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL_3D_Textures) on setting up a 3D texture.

If you then render slices through the texture array with the appropriate UVW coordinates you will get what you are after.

Comment: thanks Goz, there's actually example in OpenGL book about 3D Texture. A quick question, do you know how to load a PNG image into GLubyte array?

Comment: You'll either need to download the spec from here: http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?page=2&fc=&search=&al=P or use a PNG loader.  I'm sure you'll find one if you hunt around on line.